# mysql_query & update query is not executing

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am trying to run an update for a specific row of a table and increase by one the content of a column each time the update runs. However at certain times the query doesn't run and it does not produce an exception either. Does anyone know why this might be happening? I have tried the following:

```
$intVersion = $this->intVersion + 1;
$strSql=<<<EOT
UPDATE $this->strQueryTable SET version = '$intVersion' WHERE id = $this->id;
EOT;
$blnQueryOk = mysql_query ( $strSql );

$intVersion = $this->intVersion + 1;
$strSql =<<<EOT
UPDATE $this->strQueryTable SET version = $intVersion WHERE id = $this->id;
EOT;
$blnQueryOk = mysql_query ( $strSql );

$strSql =<<<EOT
UPDATE $this->strQueryTable SET version = version + 1 WHERE id = $this->id;
EOT;
$blnQueryOk = mysql_query ( $strSql );
```

and under all cases:

```
if (!$blnQueryOk) {
   throw new Exception(mysql_error ());
   return false;
}
```

All of them fail to update some times without producing an exception.

Comment: first of all - use this syntax {$foo} for putting variables into SQL in your case

Comment: is $this->id somehow not what you are expecting?

Comment: If you think the query is failing, use http://us2.php.net/mysql_error

echo $strSql and see what you're actually sending, and you should really be using some kind of escaping strategy: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @SergeS: braces are only necessary if the variable's a multi-dimensional array, multi-level object, or would otherwise cause the parser to be confused. eg. `$x = 42; echo "$xyz"; echo "{$x}yz";`

Comment: @Jody I am using mysql_real_escape_string before (I didn't think it is relevant with the query failing that's why I did not mention it) and I am catching the exceptions and printing the mysql_error when something goes wrong. Still I have the same problem. Any more ideas?

Comment: If only sometimes is not throwing an exception, maybe it's actually being executed but it's simply not doing what you expect and therefore you think it's not updating at all. May try echoing the $strSql to see if everything is as expected there.

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be that it is actually the database connection call which is failing (due to some database related issue like a network problem or too many mysql connections etc.). You could try doing this:

   - After your `mysql_connect()` call, verify that the db connection resource has really been created, and in case of a false return value, start throwing an exception.
2. A very common reason behind `mysql_error()` not producing anything is when you have multiple database connections open in the same process. To avoid this:

   - In all your `mysql_query()` and `mysql_error()` calls, also start passing the db connection resource as a parameter.